Redis server denying connection to localhost due to protected mode
I have a Redis server on my webhost that I launch through SSH using redis-server. When I try to connect from another SSH session using redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379 followed by ping, I receive a long message about Redis being in protected mode and only allowing connections from the loopback interface. It works fine when I launch Redis without protected mode.
My understanding is that localhost is how you connect from the loopback interface, so I'm a little confused about why it's doing this.
